# Select statement fill data in a foreach

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a php file that when clicking a 'Edit' Link it will get that job ID and list the number of rows by jobRef in my applications table.

This is just to list all of the applications for the different jobs i have available on my website.

```
<?php
require 'mysqlcon.php';
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT FROM applications WHERE applicationID = :id');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

echo "<table><tr><td>Job Reference</td><td>Job Title</td><td>Job Location</td><td>Job Description</td><td>Salary</td><td>Availability</td> <td>Category</td><td>Apply</td>";
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['applicationID']."</td>". "<td>".$row['jobRef']."</td>", "<td>".$row['fName']."</td>", "<td>".$row['lName']."</td>";
}
}

?>
```

My error is that i cannot get my code to work; I've tried using "PDO::FETCH_ASSOC" but still no help.

Any ideas on where i've gone wrong?

Comment: And where do you pass your Id parameter into query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), for binding/parameterized queries. You also need to pass the value to the query. Try this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM applications WHERE applicationID = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Your `select` query also needs the value that your are selecting. I've put in `*` which is every column. If you only want some columns list them separated by commas.

The concatenation and comma separation in your `echo` is strange but I think should work..

Final note, your `table` doesn't close; you should add a `</table>` after the `foreach`.

Final additional note for errors use, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php.

Comment: This is only listing one record? :)

Comment: Is there only one record for `applicationID = $_GET['id']`? Maybe you didn't want the `where` clause at all?

Comment: I figured out my mistake, I was looking for jobRef in my applications column. :D